# Removing/deleting part of the factor name r

Tags: r

I have a column with multiple factors. Some of them, which have otherwise the same name, have added a number in brackets that I want to remove. An example:

```
**Existing column**                 **Wanted output**

Planning phase (1:05)           Planning phase                                           
Planning phase (1:34)           Planning phase
Off site training (7:01)        Off site training
Off site training (5:30)        Off site training
Planning phase (1:28)           Planning phase
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: the one I indicated after the equal sign. Planning phase (1:05)  = Planning phase. Sorry if it was not clear

Comment: Please update it in your post so that it will be easier for others

Comment: Perhaps `gsub('(?<=\\))\\s*.*$', '', df1[,1], perl=TRUE)`

Comment: My dataframe is called c1 and the column with the factors is no.6. So I used c1$Corrections<-sub('\\s*=.*', '', c1[,6]), but it does not change anythting.

Comment: Why don't you edit your post and show the expected output?  Based on what you mentioned in the comments and in the description, your expected output can be either `Planning phase  output = Planning phase` or `Planning phase  (1:05)  output =` .

Comment: Sorry, akrun. Hopefully now it is clear.

Comment: Try  `sub('\\s*\\(.*', '', c1[,6])`

Comment: Yes it worked. Is there a way that I can sum up the numbers for each factor to compare them. I am willing to ask a new question if needed.

Comment: I am not sure how you want to sum up the numbers.  They are separated by `:`

Comment: Could you ask that as a separate question as the `sum` part is not clear to me.

Comment: @ akrun the numbers in brackets are time spent for those activities. I would like to find for example how much was spent on off site training by adding all relevant numbers. I will separate the cases for each variable, remove the words from the names like ‘off site training’ etc. (hopefully your to this question will help me figure out) and add up the numbers (after transforming time to decimals). Will ask a separate question if not able to do it. BTW I am amazed by the speed you answer difficult (at least for me) questions (it is not my first question you answered).

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  What I am confused is about adding `1:05`, `1:34` and `1:28` for the `Planned phase`.  Can you edit your post to show the expected output.

Comment: Perhaps `library(stringr); library(chron);t1 <- times(strftime(as.POSIXct(str_extract(c1$Col, '\\d+:\\d+'), format='%H:%M'), format='%H:%M:%S')); tapply(t1, c1$wantedCol, FUN=sum)`

Comment: As much as I can make sense now from your code ( I am away from R now), this is what I planned to do. I will transform hours to decimals (For example, 1:05 will become approximately 1.08, 1:34 - 1.57 etc.) and then add them all up. The challenging part for me is to remove first the words and leave just the figures (in this case removing planned phase and the brackets and have only1:05, 1:34 etc.). The rest I know how to do. Will try your code when back at the machine and will let you know. Thanks again.

Comment: I converted it to `times` and then added it up.

Comment: @akrun, I was not able to install chron so could not check if it works. I tried do the work with sub, but failed. Will be posting a new question

Comment: Thanks for the note.  Posting a new question is a good idea.

Comment: Just found a way using sapply and strsplit to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `sub`.  We match 0 or more spaces (`\\s*`) followed by parentheses (`\\(`) followed by one or more characters till the end of the string (`.*$`) and replace with `''`.

```
c1$wantedCol <- sub('\\s*\\(.*$', '', c1[,6])
c1$wantedCol
#[1] "Planning phase"    "Planning phase"    "Off site training"
#[4] "Off site training" "Planning phase"
```